# Build flatpak package from prebuild binaries (mono and gtk-sharp2 project)

Tags: build, mono, gtk#, flatpak

I'm trying to pack my application with flatpak and currently I'm stuck:

1. How do I make shure, that the runtimes are installed on the target system? I need mono, gtk-sharp2, SFML, CSFML. I learned about the basic runtime, but what about my dependencies?
2. How do I run the application? I tried

   [sven@localhost flatpak]$ flatpak-builder --run build net.sourceforge.audiocuesheet.json /app/AudioCuesheetEditor/./AudioCuesheetEditor

   bwrap: execvp /app/AudioCuesheetEditor/./AudioCuesheetEditor: No such file or directory

Some more information about the project:

net.sourceforge.audiocuesheet.json:

```
{
    "app-id": "net.sourceforge.audiocuesheet",
    "runtime": "org.gnome.Platform",
    "runtime-version": "3.26",
    "sdk": "org.gnome.Sdk",
    "command": "/AudioCuesheetEditor/AudioCuesheetEditor",
    "modules": [
        {
            "name": "AudioCuesheetEditor",
            "buildsystem": "simple",
            "build-commands": [
                "cp -r AudioCuesheetEditor /app/AudioCuesheetEditor",
                "chmod +x /app/AudioCuesheetEditor/AudioCuesheetEditor"
            ],
            "sources": [
                {
                    "type": "archive",
                    "path": "AudioCuesheetEditor-linux-x64-v2.4.2.zip",
                    "dest": "AudioCuesheetEditor"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the archive has prebuild binaries, which I would like to deploy to the target maschines. I'm new to flatpak and not really shure, if I'm doing right, so maybe some help from you would be perfect.

Thanks
Sven

Comment: I think you cannot do this with flatpak, you would need to build your dependencies with flatpak too (but I'm not an expert). You can see an example of this here: https://github.com/hbons/org.sparkleshare.SparkleShare/ (And BTW, I think this limitation is not present in snap; I think with snap you can make your package depend on other .deb packages of the system)

Comment: Well I had some discussion with someone who uses flatpak and said, it is possible to ensure the dependencies. But if that is not the case, I'm willing to use another package format, that is universal on linux distributions. I will have a look at snap.

Comment: cool, looking forward to your investigations, can you follow up here?

Comment: Yes, I now try to package by using AppImage, seems to be the easiest way, if I get to know how AppImage works ;).

Comment: nooo, why?? what was the issue with snap? IMO this is a big mistake, snap and flatpak are the ones that the industry is switching to, AppImage is legacy

Comment: Ok, but snap can not be used to build in a Virtual Maschine and currently I'm running the linux development in a VirtualBox. That is not possible with snapcraft, so I can only use flatpak or AppImage. And you told me, that I can not handle dependencies in flatpak, so only AppImage remains.

Comment: well I also said I'm not a flatpat expert (just that when I briefly looked at it this is what I think I found; and I think SparkleShare's approach is to build the deps right?)... but wait, can you tell me more about that snap limitation? I don't understand how any software would not run inside a VM but run well outside of it, especially if we're talking about something not fancy, such as a packaging tool

Comment: I did some further investigation yesterday. Snapcraft uses multipass which needs to be running. This is not possible in VirtualBox, since VirtualBox doesn't support nested virtualization. I just installed a new VM in VMWare, now I can use Snapcraft and will try to get a snapcraft running.

Comment: cool beans, any update?

Comment: Currently I'm hanging because I don't know how to build with snapcraft: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090957/package-prebuild-binaries-using-snapcraft-mono-and-gtk-sharp2

Comment: "not supported on fedora", man... snap is a product created by Canonical, try ubuntu instead :)

Comment: ping :) did you try Ubuntu?

Comment: No, I will not switch, so I better go on with flatpak or another solution.