# Package prebuild binaries using snapcraft with Fedora (mono and gtk-sharp2)

Tags: mono, packaging, gtk#, snapcraft

I'm trying to package my project using snapcraft. I think it is easiest to package the prebuild binaries, which are available here: https://sourceforge.net/p/audiocuesheet

This is a mono and gtk-sharp2 project, so I thought of using snapcraft to bundle my application. But I fight currently getting this to run.

My snapcraft.yml:

```
name: audiocuesheeteditor
version: '2.4.2'
summary: Write audio cue sheets fast and efficient
description: |
  Annoyed of writing your audio cue sheets via text editor? Here comes the solution! Audio Cuesheet Editor helps you editing your audio cuesheet file. With AudioCuesheetEditor you can import text files, edit the imported data and afterwards export to a working audio cuesheet.

apps:
  AudioCuesheetEditor:
    command: AudioCuesheetEditor/./AudioCuesheetEditor
parts:
  audiocuesheeteditor:
    source: /home/sven/Downloads/AudioCuesheetEditor-linux-x64-v2.4.2.zip
    plugin: dump
```

I have run once snapcraft, but now the second time i get the following output:

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# snapcraft 
Native builds aren't supported on Fedora. You can however use 'snapcraft cleanbuild' with a container.
```

Do you have an idea, why I can not rebuild the snap?
Also, how do I make shure, that mono and gtk-sharp2 binaries are installed on the target system?

Thanks for your help guys.
Sven

Comment: using snap on fedora? weird. if I were you, I would run this in ubuntu, and if you keep on having problems, maybe rather ask in askubuntu.com instead of stackoverflow

Comment: But I'm using fedora and will not switch. So I see, snap is not for every distribution, which makes it unattractive for me.

Comment: well, I'm sure snaps can be consumed by fedora with no difficulties, but building snaps is a different thing

Comment: What run command are you using? I generally build using snapcraft --use-lxd so that the build happens in an LXD container. Are you using multipass?